# How should I handle unknown primary keys?

Tags: primary-key, data-synchronization

I'm working as a database-administrator at a school. Recently the school upgraded its pupil administrative software into a web-based solution. This works great, but this web-based solution is missing some features which we used to have. Thankfully the new administrative software enables the possibility to synchronize local databases with *their* online database through an API.

In my **local** database each pupil used to have a primary key like `2015XXXX` where `XXXX` is some number. The online application uses a different system. As far as I see the identification number currently ranges from `XXXX` (number in the thousands) to `XXXXX` (ten thousands). I have *no idea if there exists a logic* in these numbers.

I prefer to use the new identification numbers, since it's a lot easier to keep pupils in my **local** database identical to the online system. However I wish to keep the **previous pupils** which don't have a *new* identification number. What kind of primary key should I give those, preventing a collision of primary key's?

I see some options:

1. *(what I have done so far)* I've changed previous pupils id's as a huge number. Pupil `20050123` becomes `1020050123`. The school will not reach this number of pupils any time soon. But I have nog guarantee the online system won't construct big numbers?
2. Using negative numbers? Pupil `20050123` becomes `-20050123`
3. Other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you don't know if there's any logic in the keys you can't tell if a huge or negative number will lead to a key violation.
Without knowledge of the application I'd suggest importing the previous pupils in the new software to get a regular id is the way to go.